# Spring 3.0 newbie start project not display value

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I made simple helloworld in Netbeans 7.3. But I have problem with load jsp with value from controller. I partially inspire instructions from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_tutorial.pdf (page 141.). But when I want load jsp with value which is set in controller, value is not displayed. In controller are capture GET reguests. I entered this url: `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld3/hello.htm`. I get jsp, but value not displayed. When I enter url which is write in above tutorial: 
`http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello` , I get 404 error, this page is not found. 
 What url I must enter or what I doing worse? I guess that error is in some config file. Thx

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="cz.ryska.controllers"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> 
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

dipatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                <prop key="hello.htm">helloController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

    <bean name="helloController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="hello" />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" 
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello") 
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!"); 
        return "hello"; 
    }
}
```

hello.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello!!!!!!</h1>
        <h2>${message}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/hello") 
public class MyController {
     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
         model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
         return "hello";
     } 
}
```

hello.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
        <h1>Message : ${message}</h1>
</body>
```

web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gemini.spring.mvc"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: I made new project in Netbeans and I copy your code.I change base-package on my actual controller package. I use Glassfish 3.1.2 in Netbeans 7.3. But I get warning : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWorld4] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'. And I get 404 error after start project.

Comment: to invoke controller you should open localhost:8080/context-path-if-you-have/hello

Comment: @OndřejRyška try read this at first: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html

Comment: @Georgy Gobozov context path is application name, ok? My application is called HelloWorld4. I enter http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld4/hello but I get error in netbeans glassfish console : SEVERE: PWC6117: File "C:\JavaProgramy\Spring\HelloWorld4\build\web\jsp\hello.jsp" not found

Comment: @Zagorulkin Dmitry ok thanks, this tutorial looks good, I will read this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some particular reason you coded your helloWorld application the way you did?
For a simple helloWorld application it seems needlessly complex.

For one thing unless you had a some specific reason for doing so, you don't really need to define two separate controllers.

I also worked through the tutorialspoint example you linked and mine worked perfectly, but it was a clone of the original example.

If you want to extend or play around with the example I would suggest you first clone the example and get it working... then go forward from there, one step at a time.

While I don't have my solution in front of me, the answer given by Georgy Gobozov looks correct.

Comment: And are you use Netbeans or Eclipse for this tutorial?